# How can I create a Google Classroom as an admin for another teacher using Google App Scripts?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-oauth, google-workspace, google-classroom

I am trying to create Google Classrooms programmatically for teachers.  My code works fine as long as the "owner" is me, but when I use another teacher id, I am not authorized to perform the action.  I am an administrator.

I have turned on the proper Advanced Services and have found many examples that are similar but don't have the full info. I believe I have properly set up the various authentication/OAUTH in the developers console.

```
function testCreate() {

  var newClass = Classroom.Courses.create({
  "name": 'Test Course',
  "section": 'Advisory',
  "descriptionHeading": 'This is your advisory group',
  "ownerId": [someoneElsesId]
  "guardiansEnabled": true

});
```

If `[someoneElsesId]` is "me" or my id, the behavior is exactly what I want.  I get a provisioned classroom added to my account that I have to ACCEPT or DECLINE, that was created by an administrator.

When I use another user's id, I receive the following error:
`API call to classroom.courses.create failed with error: The caller does not have permission`

I've also tried to create the classroom as me (succeeds) then add a teacher with script (gets the same error).

Comment: Are you an administrator/given permission to create classrooms for other users by the administrator in your Google domain?

Comment: I am an administrator -- unsure of where that option is in the administrator options.  My primary administrators cannot find anything that appears to address the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that being an admin isn't good enough.  In order to make this work, the script user must be running as a SuperAdmin.  After that change was made the code worked properly.